# How do I combine multiple NumPy boolean arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a two-dimensional (2D) array that contains many one-dimensional (1D) arrays of random boolean values.

```py
import numpy as np

def random_array_of_bools():
  return np.random.choice(a=[False, True], size=5)


boolean_arrays = np.array([
  random_array_of_bools(),
  random_array_of_bools(),
  ... so on
])
```

Assume that I have three arrays:

```py
[True, False, True, True, False]
[False, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, False, False]
```

This is my desired result:

```py
[False, False, True, False, False]
```

How can I achieve this with NumPy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `min` with `axis=0`:

```
>>> boolean_array.min(axis=0)
array([False, False,  True, False, False])
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [.all](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.all.html):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[True, False, True, True, False],
                [False, True, True, True, True],
                [True, True, True, False, False]])


res = arr.all(0)
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[False False  True False False]
```

Comment: Thank you! I will stick with using .min(axis=0) for now, but I see how that works as well!

Answer (score 0):

try numpy bitwise_and =>

```
out_arr = np.bitwise_and(np.bitwise_and(in_arr1, in_arr2),in_arr3)
```